# Laravel reset password form requires email to be entered

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, reset-password

When you reset password in Laravel, it sends you an email with a reset link. When you follow it, you get to a reset form. And one of the fields is an email. In `laravel-5.2` the field is automatically filled with your email. But in `laravel-5.3`, email was [removed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/37388c0a7) from reset link. Why? And why do we even need user to enter his email?

Comment: If you've forgotten your password how would you know which account to reset unless you had an email address?

Comment: @tadman Ideally, token must identify account. You've already specified email when sending reset link to your mailbox. Why do it again? From what it seems, it's just a way to not handle "token already exists" case, when generating token. Or maybe some security measure.

Comment: This seems like a question best addressed to the Laravel design team, not Stack Overflow. I think you have a valid inquiry here, but as it's not a programming problem per-se, this should probably be closed.

Comment: still a big discussion in Laravel community, but you can find some work-around solution in [this github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15733)

Comment: That gave me an idea, why they changed it. To not pass email via url. Which is probably not a good idea. Similarly to submitting login forms using GET method. That is, they solved the security issue, but didn't fix the UI.